# Just Modified this Code to Rewrite and NOT TO REDIRECT "Wildcard" Subdomains to Domain's Query String

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z0-9-_]+)\.php$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([a-z0-9-]+)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.+) http://www.domain.com/site.php?domain=%1&file=$1 [QSA]
```

First, I've redirected all naked subdomains and domain to their own top-level domains. This is the issue, I've tried to rewrite all wildcard subdomain names to the main domain's query string, but they're redirecting instead of rewriting.

For example *www.test.domain.com* is redirecting to *www.domain.com/site.php?domain=test&file=index.php* instead of writing it.

Now, how can I modify this code to make those subdomains rewritten to main domain's query string? It is possible? Maybe there's an intended flag for it! Or anything.. And any other suggestion for improvement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because when a rule's target starts with `http://some-hostname/`, the redirect is implicit, meaning you *don't need* the `R` flag to redirect, it will redirect always.

> Now, how can I modify this code to make those subdomains rewritten to main domain's query string? It is possible?

It depends, if the document root for both the subdomain and the primary domain is exactly the same, simply remove the protocol+hostname, so from:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+) http://www.example.com/site.php?domain=%1&file=$1 [QSA]
```

To:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+) /site.php?domain=%1&file=$1 [QSA]
```

But that's only if both the subdomain and primary domain goes to the same place. Otherwise, you'll have to use mod_proxy and use the `P` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+) http://www.example.com/site.php?domain=%1&file=$1 [QSA,P,L]
```

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.+) /site.php?domain=%1&file=$1 [QSA]` will just rewrite the query string of the same localhost. `[P]` flag is what I've wanted!